# How do I start 2 DispatcherTimers at the exact same time?

Tags: c#, wpf, parallel-processing, simulation

I am building a simulation where 2 players are given stats etc, and they battle it out. I have sped it up so that I can run thousands of simulations in a few minutes, and look at who won how many matchups.

All the logic seems to work great, but the one problem I am having is that in an equal matchup, where both players are exactly the same, Player 1 wins more often than player 2 consistently. The best I have had over a large sample was 45.2% wins to player 2 in the equal matchup.

At the beginning of a match simulation, I am starting up 4 DispatcherTimers - One for each weapon of both players.
I have ordered the timer starts so that it starts player 1's main hand, player 2's main hand. Then Player 1's offhand, then player 2's offhand.

I then put the 4 timer stars in a parallel.invoke() but with this, I got the 45.2% win rate to Player 2.

How could I make this more accurate, and assume that they both start attacking at EXACTLY the same time?

FYI, here is the paralell.Invoke I am using to start all 4 timers:

```
Parallel.Invoke(() =>
{
    if (Items.Single(i => i.ID == Player1.MainHand).RelatedLevel == "Melee" || Items.Single(i => i.ID == Player1.MainHand).RelatedLevel == "Range" || Items.Single(i => i.ID == Player1.MainHand).RelatedLevel == "Mage")
    {
        P1MainHandTimer.DoSomething += P1MainHandSwing;
        if (FASimulations == 1)
        {
            P1MainHandTimer.Start(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(P1MainHandAttackSpeed * 1000 * (1 / FASpeed))));
        }
        else
        {
            P1MainHandTimer.Start(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(P1MainHandAttackSpeed * 1000 * (1 / 50))));
        }
    }
},
() =>
{
    if (Items.Single(i => i.ID == Player2.MainHand).RelatedLevel == "Melee" || Items.Single(i => i.ID == Player2.MainHand).RelatedLevel == "Range" || Items.Single(i => i.ID == Player2.MainHand).RelatedLevel == "Mage")
    {
        P2MainHandTimer.DoSomething += P2MainHandSwing;
        if (FASimulations == 1)
        {
            P2MainHandTimer.Start(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(P2MainHandAttackSpeed * 1000 * (1 / FASpeed))));
        }
        else
        {
            P2MainHandTimer.Start(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(P2MainHandAttackSpeed * 1000 * (1 / 50))));
        }
    }
},
() =>
{
    if (Items.Single(i => i.ID == Player1.OffHand).RelatedLevel == "Melee" || Items.Single(i => i.ID == Player1.OffHand).RelatedLevel == "Range" || Items.Single(i => i.ID == Player1.OffHand).RelatedLevel == "Mage")
    {
        P1OffHandTimer.DoSomething += P1OffHandSwing;
        if (FASimulations == 1)
        {
            P1OffHandTimer.Start(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(P1OffHandAttackSpeed * 1000 * (1 / FASpeed))));
        }
        else
        {
            P1OffHandTimer.Start(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(P1OffHandAttackSpeed * 1000 * (1 / 50))));
        }
    }
},
() =>
{
    if (Items.Single(i => i.ID == Player1.OffHand).RelatedLevel == "Melee" || Items.Single(i => i.ID == Player1.OffHand).RelatedLevel == "Range" || Items.Single(i => i.ID == Player1.OffHand).RelatedLevel == "Mage")
    {
        P2OffHandTimer.DoSomething += P2OffHandSwing;
        if (FASimulations == 1)
        {
            P2OffHandTimer.Start(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(P2OffHandAttackSpeed * 1000 * (1 / FASpeed))));
        }
        else
        {
            P2OffHandTimer.Start(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(P2OffHandAttackSpeed * 1000 * (1 / 50))));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure synchronizing timers will help? Timers are pretty inaccurate. If you are running simulation, then either use single thread or count ticks (means single timer).

Comment: Depends on the granularity you're looking for. If you want *EXACTLY* the same time then the answer is: You don't (or rather: can't). If the granularity is *roughly within a second*, you may *more or less* be able to *come close to* achieving what you want. I'd say the problem needs a different solution.

Comment: ...and (and I'm guessing that you're after a 50% win percentage in these cases) one of those would be: "If everything is equal, return 50%". If this is an invariant you expect to be true if they are exactly equally matched, you might as well spell it out, and return just that.

Comment: As an aside: Keep in mind that the `Parallel.Invoke()` does not mean: **Start these actions at the same time and run them in parallel**, rather it means **Execute these actions, and if possible, do so in parallel**.